# how to make js display random word from an list on a click of a button and print it in a heading 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

how to make js display random word from an list on a click of a button and print it in a heading 3? I need a quick reply. Please, would appreciate a quick reply

//Start of Js code

```
let display = document.getElementById("motivato");
console.log(display)

var motivation = [{
quote: "Planting popcorn does not produce more popcorn",
person: "Farmer Ted"
}, {
quote: "White whale, bad whale",
person: "Confucious (Moby Dick)"
}, {
quote: "Use the strobe function to disorientate your attacker",
person: "Flashlight"
}, {
quote: "Apply liberally to your erogenous zones",
person: "Spice Bomb"
}, {
quote: "Help me, I'm bleaching",
person: "The Great Barrier Reef"
}];

function motivateMe() {
  var listLength =  Object.keys(motivation).length;
  var randVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * listLength);
  document.write(motivation[randVal]);
  display.innerHTML = motivation;
}
```

Please edit my code and reply below

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to print a random word from within the objects or a random object?

Comment: You probably don't want to be using document.write (unless you really mean to write it all). Why is the line following trying to put the whole of motivation into the innerHTML rather than the selected quote?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you meant you wanted to generate a random quote and not just one word.

Here's the answer:

```js
const motivation = [{
        quote: "Planting popcorn does not produce more popcorn",
        person: "Farmer Ted"
    }, {
        quote: "White whale, bad whale",
        person: "Confucious (Moby Dick)"
    }, {
        quote: "Use the strobe function to disorientate your attacker",
        person: "Flashlight"
    }, {
        quote: "Apply liberally to your erogenous zones",
        person: "Spice Bomb"
    }, {
        quote: "Help me, I'm bleaching",
        person: "The Great Barrier Reef"
}];

const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * motivation.length);

console.log(motivation[randomNumber]);

const generate_quote = () => {
  const quote = motivation[randomNumber].quote;
    document.getElementById("random_quote").innerHTML = quote;
}
```

```html
<p id="random_quote">The random quote will appear here.</p>

<button onclick="generate_quote()">Generate random quote</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const display = document.getElementById("motivato");

const motivation = [{
  quote: "Planting popcorn does not produce more popcorn",
  person: "Farmer Ted"
}, {
  quote: "White whale, bad whale",
  person: "Confucious (Moby Dick)"
}, {
  quote: "Use the strobe function to disorientate your attacker",
  person: "Flashlight"
}, {
  quote: "Apply liberally to your erogenous zones",
  person: "Spice Bomb"
}, {
  quote: "Help me, I'm bleaching",
  person: "The Great Barrier Reef"
}];

function motivateMe() {
  const listLength = motivation.length;
  const randVal = motivation[Math.floor(Math.random() * listLength)];
  display.innerHTML = `<q>${randVal.quote}</q><br><br><small>${randVal.person}</small>`;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="motivateMe()">Motivate me!</button>
<h3 id="motivato"></h3>
```

Now you need to edit the above to make sure that a button press doesn't return the same quote as the previous one, as when it does it seems like the button doesn't work.